# Why Textfield not accepting input in flutter?

Tags: flutter

When I enter input in TextField. if two digit's sum is true it calls reload().after that two random numbers are generating. but when I again give input its not working. I have to click TextField Everytime to give input.

I used FocusNode to keep focus but its not working.

TextField

```
TextField(
                    focusNode: nd_input,
                    autofocus: true,
                    controller: input,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      fun_sum(value);
                      FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(nd_input);
                      setState(() {

                      });
                    },
```

fun_sum function

```
void fun_sum(var value){
int sum = num1 + num2;
print("Sum :${sum}");
if(sum == int.parse(value)){
  setState(() {
  input.text = "";
  reload();
  });
}
```

}

reload function

```
 void reload(){
field_one();
field_two();
setState(() {
});
```

}

Comment: Could you please provide a complete minimal case, that is runnable?

Answer (score 0):

I think **setState()** function causes problem for you. Try this:

**Your TextField**

```
TextField(
  focusNode: nd_input,
  autofocus: true,
  controller: input,
  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
  onChanged: (value) {
    setState(() {
      fun_sum(value);
      FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(nd_input);
    });
  },
```

**fun_sum Function**

```
void fun_sum(var value){
int sum = num1 + num2;
print("Sum :${sum}");
if(sum == int.parse(value)){
  input.text = "";
  reload();
}
```

**reload Function**

```
void reload(){
  field_one();
  field_two();
}
```

You don't need to call **setState()** recursively.
Let me know if this helps.

Comment: No, still no difference.

Comment: @FenilTrivedi, so you're trying to hold focus on your TextField while updating state?

Comment: yes, it's focused and showing keyboard but not taking input.